# get distance from all samples in knn in opencv

Tags: opencv, distance, sample, knn

as i know knn find smallest distance from all samples.it means it is the nearest sample. but what if i want distance of my new data from all samples? how can I get for example 3 or 4 nearest samples to my new data?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K nearest neighbour? That means that you can find K nearest samples. You should read documentation carefully. 
Example:

```
    kdtree.knnSearch(((cv::Mat)objects_coordinates[i_pts]).t(),
        indices, dists, num_of_neighbours, cv::flann::SearchParams(32));
```

Comment: Thank you but I think i don't know the basics for using kdtree for knn search. would you please address me some where to see an example of use of kdtree in opencv?

Comment: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/clustering_and_search_in_multi-dimensional_spaces.html